# Kafka connect property relation between partition.duration.ms and flush size?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Can some one explain the significance of partition.duration.ms and flushsize in below configuration.
What should be the thought behind setting up these properties?

```
"connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
  "s3.region": "eu-central-1",
  "partition.duration.ms": "1000",
  "topics.dir": "root_bucket",
  "flush.size": "10",
  "topics": "TEST_SRV",
  "tasks.max": "1",
  "s3.part.size": "5242880",
  "timezone": "UTC",
  "locale": "US",
  "key.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
  "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat",
  "partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner",
  "schema.generator.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.hive.schema.DefaultSchemaGenerator",
  "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "storage.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
  "s3.bucket.name": "events-dev-s3",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
  "path.format": "'year'-YYYY/'month'-MM/'day'-dd/'hour'-HH",
  "timestamp.extractor": "RecordField",
  "timestamp.field": "event_data.created_at"
```

Comment: Did you managed to make it work, creating a file every 1 sec and saving it into an "hour" folder? if so can you share the config? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partition duration determines how often the time based partitioner creates a new "path.format". In your case, a 1 second partition duration doesn't make sense because you've set the partitioner to only make hourly partitions. Did you mean to include minute and seconds in `path.format`? If not, you should be using HourlyPartitioner class.

Then the flush size is an upper boundary for how many Kafka records will exist in any given file

---

The thought behind the values depends on the throughput of your topics and how much delay you're willing to tolerate before you will be reading the records from S3 rather than directly off of Kafka.

Note that you pay for every S3 scan, so a higher flush and less overall files would help save money

Comment: Thanks @cricket. In that partition.duration.ms should be set for 1 hour , if thats what it concludes?

Comment: You are also paying per file write operation, which also means that fewer larger files will cost you less money.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding other answer

> a 1 second partition duration doesn't make sense because you've set the partitioner to only make hourly partitions.

The partitioner has **not** been set to only make hourly partitions.

`"path.format": "'year'-YYYY/'month'-MM/'day'-dd/'hour'-HH"`

This sets the **directory structure granularity** to an **hour**

`"partition.duration.ms": "1000"`

This configures the connector to output a file for each 'second' worth of data (..per input partition)

The files will be written to the 'hourly' directories that encompasses the 'second' the file was generated for.

I.E. The hourly directories will contain all the data for that hour (in this case, all of the per-second files)